# How do I run a bash script in localhost from an airflow docker container?

Tags: docker, airflow

Idea is to run an airflow job to update packages on localhost machine; On host machine airflow is running in docker container.

Comment: You don't - the point of running containers is to isolate from host environment.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arkadiusz mentioned, your tasks will be isolated from the host. However, it's not something you "can't" achieve.. as part of your BashOperator (or SSHOperator) you can do a ssh to the host and run the command/script (if it's really required)